# Django 2.1 - can't link my models variables in html file

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-templates

I'm having some problems to design my templates files in Django 2.1
at the index.html of my app I can get in at the details page although when I want to design my detail page in the html file I put the references but the browser gives me nothing.

MY MODELS.PY
from django.db import models

```
class Dreams (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objetivo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    imagem = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo + ' - ' + self.objetivo


class Wish (models.Model):
    lets = models.ForeignKey(Dreams, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    it = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.make
```

MY VIEWS.PY

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from .models import Dreams, Wish
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    all_dreams = Dreams.objects.all()
    contexto = {'all_dreams': all_dreams}
    return render(request, 'index.html', contexto)


def detail(request, Dreams_id):
    try:
        titulo = Dreams.objects.get(pk=Dreams_id)
        contexto = {'titulo': titulo}
    except Dreams.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("sem sonhos")
    return render(request, 'detail.html', contexto)
```

MY detail.html FILE

```
<img src = {{ dreams.imagem }}>
<h2>{{ titulo }}</h2>
<h3>{{ wish.make }}</h3>
```

but the only thing that I get is the 'titulo' in `<h2>`. I've tried to create variables in views for 'imagem' and 'make' and got nothing.
again thanks for your time.

Comment: Well there can be zero, one, or *multiple* `Wich` objects, not just one. So your template does not make much sense for me.

Comment: You haven't supplied `dreams` or `wich` in the context

Comment: yeah but they should be linked for de id how do i do that?

i tried to add make = wich.make at the the views and then added {'make':make} at the context but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct, you just misused the objects in your template. If you pass an object to your template you can access its attributes by using the `.` notation. I changed your `detail` view in a way, that the variables make more sense when you access them in the template.

```
def detail(request, Dreams_id):
    try:
        dream = Dreams.objects.get(pk=Dreams_id)
        contexto = {'dream': dream}
    except Dreams.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("sem sonhos")
    return render(request, 'detail.html', contexto)
```

You can now access the title and the image by using `{{ dream.titulo }}` and `{{ dream.imagem }}`.

```
<img src="{{ dream.imagem }}">
<h2>{{ dream.titulo }}</h2>
```

To access your referenced `Wich` objects, you have to know that Django automatically creates a [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) by adding an attribute `<model>_set` to the referenced model. In your case `dream.wich_set`. This is an instance of a [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) and provides methods like `.filter()`, `.all()`, ... for fetching the objects from the database.

This reverse relation is a One-To-Many relation. That is why we are getting multiple results and have to iterate over them in the template using a [for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)-loop

```
<img src="{{ dream.imagem }}">
<h2>{{ dream.titulo }}</h2>
{% for wich in dream.wich_set.all %}
    <h3>{{ wich.make }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Additionally I would recommend using an [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) instead of a `CharField` to store your image. Each image stored in an `ImageField` (which inherits all methods and attributes from the FileField) has an [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) attribute, which is suitable for the `src` attribute of an `img` tag, eg. `<img src="{{ dream.imagem.url}}">`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH  explained the world for me could i add you, please?

Comment: how do i gave you a gold medal you deserve it

Answer (score 1):

At first I will suggest to use [get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of try, except.
Now let me come to the main point. If you want to access any variable in template the you should and you must send it through [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects). You are sending dream object in the form of `titulo` variable in context so to access image field you have to use

```
<img src = {{ titulo.imagem }}>
```

instead of

```
<img src = {{ dreams.imagem }}>
```

As well as if you want to use `wich` in template the you have to make sure you want which `wich` and send it via context from view or have to access all `wich` related to the dreams object(titulo) using `titulo.wich_set.all`  which will return you all the wich related to the dream(tutilo) object and you can loop through it.